# UNIX: Grep a specific word and all the text following it

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I have a variable in Unix, that stores multiple lines of alpha-numeric characters. I want to grep to a specific word and get all the text following it.

For example, `$Variable` contains:

```
Hello, User

Your files are:

File1 : Exists

File2 : None
```

Let us say I want to find File2, which is the last line and I want if it is Yes or None or whatever text is present after the colon and save it to another variable.

Comment: Can you give an example in your question?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Same line - eg: till the end of present, as in the above example

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: So, you want to see each line containing the word, starting from the word to the end of the line?  If the word is `fox` and the line is `the fox and eagle out-foxed the badger`, does it matter which of the two sequences `fox` is found?  It is, perhaps surprisingly, harder to print the first (at least in the mechanisms I'm thinking of).  Also, does `out-foxed` count as containing the word `fox`, or are you looking for `fox` without preceding or following alphabetic characters?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler No, I don't have repeated words in a line. Just want to find the line starting with that word and save it to a variable again

Answer (score 2):

Use sed instead

```
sed -n '/the word you are looking for/,$p' <file name>
```

or since you said it was in a variable something more like:

```
echo "$variable" | sed -n '/the word you are looking for/,$p'
```

sed -n says do not print.

the pattern says from "the word you are looking for" to $ which is the end of file do the p command which is print :)

If you have to stop before the end of the file then you have to replace $ with the end pattern

If you just want to save the results to another variable:

```
new_variable=$(echo "$variable" | sed -n '/the word you are looking for/,$p')
```

Also note that is the string you are looking for has / in it then you must escape it with \ so it would look like

```
new_variable=$(echo "$variable" | sed -n '/the word you are\/ looking for/,$p')
```

Comment: Can I save this to another variable without printing it ?

Answer (score 1):

So you have a variable defined as:

```
$ var="abc\ndef\nghi\njkl\nmn"
```

Then, if you want to print "line" containing "ghi" and following this way:

```
$ echo -e $var | sed -n '/ghi/,$p'
```

Answer (score 1):

`grep` is to **G**lobally search for a **R**egular **E**xpression and **P**rint the matching string. That is not what you want to do, you want to take a **S**tream of input and **ED**it it to output part of it. Guess what tool does THAT in UNIX.

```
$ echo "$var"
Hello, User

Your files are:

File1 : Exists

File2 : None
$ var2=$(echo "$var" | sed -n 's/^File2 : //p')
$ echo "$var2"
None
```

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
variable="Hello, User
Your files are:
File1 : Exists
File2 : None"
```

You can get the information for `File2` into another variable `file2` using:

```
file2=$(echo "$variable" | sed -n '/File2/ s/File2 *: *//p')
```

The double quotes preserve newlines in the variable.  The `-n` suppresses the default printing.  The pattern matches the line containing `File2` followed by any number of spaces, a colon and any number of additional spaces; it is replaced by nothing, and the remainder of the line is printed by `sed` and that is captured in the variable `file2`.  If there can be spaces in front of `File2` in the data, you can arrange to match and remove them too.